# Cursor showing under link way far

Tags: css, frontend

I have noticed a weird behavior in my different browsers, when i hover a text link from the bottom, the cursor start showing under the link even before hovering the text, the size of the text is 85px while the line-height is 61px.

```
font-size: 85px;
line-height: 61px;
```

is it because the text is big?! here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/rcdsqf2e/

I had to add a transparent bloc to avoid this situation, is there a better solution to make the cursor appear only the the area of the link

[image]

Comment: Style the link with `outline: 1px solid red;` to see the link's hit box.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet for this? May be there is some padding or something else.

Comment: I have checked everything, there is no padding or marging, i think if you set a big font-size you will get the same thing https://jsfiddle.net/rcdsqf2e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Normal Behaviour

I believe this is normal behavior. [Consider this HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/y79c5u48/10/):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Normal link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ag</a></li>
</ul>
```

When Hovering over letters in a link, there needs to be room for letters that go below the "line" (as in the line one would write on), such the lowercase letters "g" or "y".

## Potential Fix

As for how to fix your issue, I think the best way of doing so would be to [use pseudo elements](https://jsfiddle.net/xnkh23r7/) to change the cursor.

```
a {
  position: relative;
}
a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  cursor: default;
  
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

## Better Fix

I have edited my message to share a better solution, as I was not satisfied with the one I shared before.
Simply [add `overflow: hidden`](https://jsfiddle.net/t7pbaxu2/) to your the "a" tags.

```
a {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

however, this will cut off letters that go below the "writing line", as shown in the [above linked example](https://jsfiddle.net/t7pbaxu2/). If you wish to not cut off these letters in the future, you could either remove the `overflow: hidden;`, or add padding:

```
a {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what i did ;)